# How to read text file into table variable using bcp command

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

I have text file which contains below value,
ABC
PQR
ALM
kkk
ppp
etc....

How to read these values in table variable using bcp command

Comment: Please define file format and provide some sample data.

Comment: I have posted the detail question here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907024/how-to-read-text-file-into-table-variable-using-bcp-command

Comment: @mohammadmohabbati I have posted the detail question here:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52907024/how-to-read-text-file-into-table-variable-using-bcp-command