# How to read text file into @table variable using bcp command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, bcp

I have below text file having different words inside it:

[image: Text file having words]

My aim is to insert only 4 character words from the text file into a table variable which is `@temp`, using bcp command.

So, at the end, the table variable `@temp` will look like below:

[image: @temp]

Comment: Why would you want to put them into a variable? That would only persist for the duration of the BCP command; making the entire task pointless. If you're using BCP, you need to put the data into an actual table, not a variable.

Comment: You can't - nor would it be useful. A table variable has too limited a scope and lifetime. So rather than discuss the problems with the path you have chosen, discuss your ultimate goal. What do you intend to do with this table once populated?

Comment: @Larnu I want to apply further logic on the data taken in the table variable and then final result set will be written to another text file, result.txt. Thus, I do not need the table variable after the final sorted data is written in another text file, result.txt. Also, if I use actual table then every time before loading the test.txt in to actual table, I will have to empty the table ( in case test.txt contains different words ) and then load the 4 character words in it and then apply the logic described above. Is it for sure that, in this case, table variable can not be used ?

Comment: @SMor I want to apply further logic on the data taken in the table variable and then final result set will be written to another text file, result.txt. Thus, I do not need the table variable after the final sorted data is written in another text file, result.txt. Also, if I use actual table then every time before loading the test.txt in to actual table, I will have to empty the table ( in case test.txt contains different words ) and then load the 4 character words in it and then apply the logic described above. Is it for sure that, in this case, table variable can not be used ?

Comment: This sounds like you need to use a staging table. For the reasons both @SMor and I have given, a variable is not the right choice here as it won't persist once the BCP has completed (which means it won't exist when you try to apply further logic to it). A variable only exists within the batch that declared it. As soon as that batch ends, so does the existence of the variable.

Comment: And one last comment. At this point, you have provided no reason to think that using tsql has any advantage or is a reasonable tool for this. However, no one but you knows what "apply further logic" really means. To take the contents of one file, do something, and then save it as another file does not seem to fit the design of tsql or a database generally. SSIS might be useful if you wish to learn it. Otherwise I suggest a good gen purpose language in which you have experience.

Comment: This really sounds like a job for SSIS where things like this are done all the time.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a table where you will store the data coming from your file:

   ```
   create table import(WORDS nvarchar(100))
   ```
2. Import data from file with bcp into the table created in the first step:

   ```
   bcp [test].[dbo].[import] in d:\test.txt -c -T
   ```
3. Declare `@table` variable:

   ```
   declare @table table ([ID] int identity(1,1), WORDS nvarchar(100))
   ```
4. Insert into `@table` variable only words with length = 4:

   ```
   insert into @table 
   select WORDS 
   from import
   where len(WORDS) <= 4
   ```

Now `@table` variable contains this data:

[image]